# CSS - Bootstrap Scrollspy - how to change color according section background

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I had a bootstrap nav with scrollspy - fixed and without background color.

When I scroll down I have different sections, with different backgrounds colors.

Then I need a solution to change de font color of nav to contrast with the section background.

I not so expert in CSS - then, sorry if its a dummy question - but there is a way to do this?

Change the font of nav for each section?

AND, its possible to hide navbar in some sections (like home section, where I have another navigation menu)

tks!

Comment: Please, can you give us any code?

Comment: Hi @FabianSierra tks a lot for your time! of course! I'm writing a Jsdfiddle right now - but I'm using a simple code (basic the bootstrap example).

Comment: Give each section a unique class name and add font-color based on your background colour of that section

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_scrollspy.asp  Refer how they set different background colours for each section, you can define font properties as well...

Comment: @Gaurravs tks for your time! I tried to add the class name for each section (I test with 1) and still not working. I create a class navsection with {color: #FFF) for a section with black background - and the nav stills with black font in all sections.. (I add the class on <section class="navsection"> - I test this adding on style a ".navsection" class and a "#navbar .navsection" class (because the navbar id is navbar). tks!

Comment: while assigning properties with value. add !important to it go give high priority

Answer (score 1):

Okay so I made an example. I hope this is what you were looking for:

http://jsfiddle.net/gpcasx24/3/

The following piece of javascript (requires jquery) checks when scrollspy notices that the user entered a new section and checks what section it is. It extracts the name of the section and grabs a color, you can define, from the array `ColorForSection`.

```
// Change this to define your colors. Can also be rgb(0,0,0) etc
var ColorForSection = {
  '#moose': '#ff0000',
  '#bear': "#00ff00",
  '#beaver': "#0000ff",
  '#raccoon': "#ffff00",
  '#bobcat': "#00ffff",
}

// Change the navbar's link color to a defined one based on the active nav link
function ChangeNavColor() {
        // Get the section name from the navbar' now active URL
    var currentSection = $(".nav li.active > a").attr('href');
    // Set the link color
    $(".nav a:link").css('color', ColorForSection[currentSection]);  
}

// When scrollspy activates a new section, execute the ChangeNavColor function
$(document).on('activate.bs.scrollspy', ChangeNavColor);

// Call the function when the navbar's done loading
// So we also have the correct color to begin with.
$('.nav').ready(ChangeNavColor);
```

If your link's href is not `#blabla` then let me now and I'll change the code!

**To hide your navbar when at the top of your page:**
Use this piece of code:

```
// Execute the function when the page is scrolled
$(document).scroll(function() {
  // Get the navbar
  var nav = $('nav');
  // Enable the class 'hidden' if scrollTop is lower or equal to 2
  nav.toggleClass('hidden', $(document).scrollTop() <= 2);
});
```

The toggleClass works like this. You can tell what class to toggle, in this case 'hidden' and whether it should be present or not, indicated by `true` or `false` in the second parameters.

`$(document).scrollTop() <= 2`
Checks if the scroll amount is less than 2 pixels. You could change this to equals to 0 if you want it to be hidden at the absolute top.
Or change 2 to the height of your **home** section.

**To hide your navbar for a specific section:**
Try the following:

```
// Sections to hide the nav in
var HideNavInSections = [
    '#moose'
];

// Hide nav for specified sections
function HideNavOnScroll() {
    // Get the section name from the navbar' now active URL
    var currentSection = $(".nav li.active > a").attr('href');
    // Should we hide the nav in this section?
    $('.nav').toggleClass('hidden', HideNavInSections.indexOf(currentSection) != -1);
}

// When scrollspy activates a new section, execute the HideNavOnScroll function  
$(document).on('activate.bs.scrollspy', HideNavOnScroll);
```

Comment: hi @Tim-van-Osch - first of all tks for your time! Great script!! I'm still testing here, and I'm trying to make some customs - I'm not na expert em js, but I understand your script and create a BgColorForSection option - Works fine too - but I have 2 problems - 1- the New Color prevail against the active spy color. (if spy color is red - now all color are blue). I make a test creating a $(".nav .active a").css('color', BgColorForSection[currentSection]); - its Works and change the color only for the spy link. But if I do this with the 'background-color' the color "fixes" forever...

Comment: @DANIEL Do you want to change the background color for the navbar links or sections? I can create a jsfiddle / update my answer with that and an explanation if you'd like.

Comment: I think I need a way to clear the bgcolor to restore the original status.. (I'm testing) -  but with this knowledge I think I can create border, or any other css style to custom the spy nav for each background. and my problem 2: there is a way to HIDE the nav for a especific section? I dont want the nav on my home because I had another menu bar there.. tkss!! :D

Comment: Okay, I'll edit my answer in a minute. I assume your **home** is at the top of your webpage?

Comment: @DANIEL I've edited my answer with further explanation.

Comment: @DANIEL I'm going to bed now ;) If this answers your question consider marking it as an **answer**. I hope I helped you.

Comment: hi @tim-van-osch! tkkkkkkkkkkks!! I tested a lot the script and create a jsdfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gpcasx24/4/. (home is the top of my webpage, but in the jsfiddle I create another top call "MENU" - because I test first the changeNavColor function - and before the HideNavOnScroll (then  I create this new top with a new menu to hidden the nav). Problems: 1- On ChangeNavColor - The script have a "memory effect" - If I put a new effect the script memorize for the other section. If I put a border, the border never disappear anymore. (continue...)

Comment: then I create this $(".nav a").css('background-color', 'transparent'); to reset the background to transparent and $(".nav a").css('border', '0px'); to reset the border. That's the best way to do this or have another way to do? because I need to reset each custom item. 2- on HideNav - I test booth options, Works fine!! but only after I click on menu, not onload.. I tried to put onload function, but with this all menu and nav menu disapears.

Comment: Your hard work deserves a thumbs up whether it was resolved or not.